# Why do I need to include <stdio.h> to use CUDA's printf()?

Tags: c++, cuda, printf, gpu

I want to `printf()` something in my CUDA kernel. The Programming Guide [suggests](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#examples) I do that like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

__global__ void helloCUDA(float f)
{
    printf("Hello thread %d, f=%f\n", threadIdx.x, f);
}
```

But this is simply including the standard C library's `stdio.h`. Why would that be necessary? CUDA's `printf()` doesn't have the same behavior of stdio's `printf()`; and I certainly don't need most of everything else that's in there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an implementation detail you don't need to know about which stems from limitations in the CUDA syntax (basically it is illegal to define different `__device__` and `__host__` versions of the same function).

The standard library prototype is used as a proxy in device code during compilation, and when compiling for a supported architecture, some sneaky template overloading is used to insert the device implementation into the device code.

Comment: so could you just forward declare it and it would do the same thing?

Comment: @RussellGreene: That's a good question I don't have an answer to. If you could get the prototype to match the exact target libC implementation the CUDA front end expects to see, it should work (at least in theory). But that seems like a lot of effort versus just  including `cstdio` and accepting there is magic going on under the hood to make it work.

Comment: I would still expect NVIDIA to tell me to `#include "cuda_printf.h"` and have them do their magic inside.

Comment: @einpoklum: but you can't do that because of language limitations unless you are willing to never be able to use host and device printf in the same translation unit. The limitations of how `__device__` and `__host__` work prevent it

Comment: I'm going to split hairs a bit and ask: Well, if that's the case, why don't they just tell you to use `magic_suffix_printf()` instead of `printf()` to avoid this naming issue?

Comment: They originally *did* do that (google cuprintf if you are interested). But when  they implemented hardware support for kernel printing, they changed to printf. And I would guess the reason is that they are *slowly* implementing parts of the standard library on the device (printf,  malloc, memcpy, pretty much all of math.h, etc). I guess the thinking is that is is less confusing. printf works *exactly* like the host implementation,  even down to the need to include <stdio.h>. If you want an argument about it, write to NVIDIA. I am not them

Comment: By design, CUDA relies on host system's header files for standard C/C++ library functions. This doesn't only apply to `printf()`, also device-side `malloc()`, `free()`, `memset()`, all standard math functions. The reason for this was a desire to maximize interoperability between host and device code. Since some CUDA-internal header files also include some host header files (e.g. `math_functions.h` includes `math.h`) you may sometimes get away with not including the host headers in a CUDA program. You can provide your own `printf()` prototype, provided it matches the one in the host header file

Comment: As a clarification, the GPU hardware was not changed specifically to support kernel printing. In sm_20 the GPU architecture was modified so it could support a proper ABI, on top of which all kind of standard C++ functionality, including `printf()`, then could be implemented. There is no ABI on GPUs with sm_1x architectures.

Comment: So, I accepted this answer, but I think it's ridiculous. I mean, nVIDIA's choice to pseudo-override printf that way, not the answer here.